# how to adjust script to respond to screen width

Tags: javascript, media-queries

can anybody help with this please?

My script is presenting a dropdown menu, I need to adjust it's height for mobile devices. I'd normally do this with media queries but in this case I'm not.

So I need to check, if screen width > 768 maxH = "306px", else maxH = "450px" - but I'm not sure exactly on how to write it.

```
function toggleNavPanel(x) {                

            var panel = document.getElementById(x),
                navarrow = document.getElementById("navarrow"), 

               //checking for screen width here and defining maxH                 

               //maxH = "306px";

                if (window.screen.availWidth > 768) {
                     maxH = "450px";
                  } else {
                    maxH = "306px";
                  }

            if (panel.style.height == maxH) {
                panel.style.height = "0px";
                panel.color = "#000000";
                //navarrow.innerHTML = "menu";
                navarrow.classList.remove('menuX');
                navarrow.classList.add('menuLines');
            } 
            else {
                panel.style.height = maxH;
                panel.color = "#ffffff";
                //navarrow.innerHTML = "close";
                navarrow.classList.remove('menuLines');
                navarrow.classList.add('menuX');                    
            }
        }
```

You can see the script in action here
http://www.dougcowan.net.nz/article/placeholding-test-article-for-testing

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen dimensions via `window.screen.availWidth` and `window.screen.availHeight`. For more information on the screen API, go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen .

```
if (window.screen.availWidth > 768) {
  // Your code here.
} else {
  // Your code here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your suggestion (see edited above). It doesn't work yet.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but it appears your nav layout is responding when I change the window width, which is what I think you are trying to do. If you haven't spent too much time designing your page, I would consider using a framework like Bootstrap, if you are worried about making a mobile friendly layout. It is much easier than writing your own media queries or listening for onresize events.

Comment: Hi, and thanks.  If you look at this link, http://www.dougcowan.net.nz/articles/testing.html it has the modified code in it and unfortunately the drop-down no longer works. I just want to change the height of the drop-down so that it doesn't cut off the navigation on phone devices. Unfortunately I am locked into the layout as I've been asked to add to the existing setup.

Comment: I decided to go with your advice and use the Bootstrap navigation in the end, it was easier than trying to fight against things not wanting to work for me and I can control the styling. Thanks again for your attention Kyle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.outerWidth` and `window.outerHeight`.